# UnicodeEncodeError when attempting to create a RAID-1 Ubuntu Server

Tags: 18.04, python, raid, environment-variables, mdadm

I'm attempting to create a home NAS(Plex) using Ubuntu.  I have two 8tb Seagate Ironwolf drives I'll be using in RAID-1 for the storage portion and I've also got a random 500gb drive that'll be used for booting (which I've heard is needed).

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 to setup my system and I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWGUcoZDuEc

I was able to make it up until https://youtu.be/SWGUcoZDuEc?t=386 where then as it actually started creating the raid array it ran into some UnicodeEncodeError.  I'm not super familiar with Linux in general so I've got a phone photo of the error.

[image]
After the error occurs I've tried going into the terminal and setting some environment variables by doing things like

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

but every time I've tried to run the installation and checked the environment variables afterwards, the environment variables I set the previous (attempted) installation seem to have been reset to their default.

The error seems to be similar to these errors:
https://github.com/Leo-G/Flask-Scaffold/wiki/unicodeEncodeError:-%27ascii%27-codec-can%27t-encode-character-on-Python-3.4.3-on-Ubuntu-14.04

https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard/issues/61

I've tried running through their solutions but my intuition says they won't work because they're setting environment variables which in my testing seem to get reset every time I go through the setup process from my Bootable USB.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
When I ran into this issue I was using Ubuntu Server 18.04.3.  I've now (as far as I can tell) have it working by using the older version of Ubuntu Server, 18.04.1

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests this is a bug in either `subiquity` or in one of its dependencies.

Please file a bug report at their project site:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity